# iOS 7 - UITableViewController in a PopOver could find segue with error Receiver(UITableViewController ) has no segue with identifier

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uipopovercontroller

I am building a Search Table View Controller in a PopOver window. I created a manual segue to transition from the TableView to a detail view controller. The segue identifier assigned in storyboard and in code are the same and it is hooked up to the view controller, not to the table view cell. I have cleaned up, rebuilt but the issue is still appearing. Below is the code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"details" sender:self];
}
```

Every time  I get into the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` function I would get the error

```
reason: 'Receiver (<TableViewController: 0x8a705b0>) has no segue with identifier 'details'
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ctrl-click on the table view cell or inspect it's connections? I was able to get that same error message out a project I'm working on by calling the same performSegue method in a table view cell with no connections. Since the segue is hooked up to your view controller and not your table view cell prototype, that might explain why you keep getting the error message.